# FOR INSERT trigger not firing

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, triggers, sql-server-2008-r2

I am having a problem with the insert trigger

this is my trigger code :

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
create TRIGGER [dbo].[Vtriggers] ON [dbo].[stats]
FOR INSERT
AS
INSERT INTO [NewDB].dbo.NewStat (StatID)
SELECT ID
FROM inserted
```

the weird thing is , i build another table exact like the table that i want to make trigger in it and trigger works for new one , but on old one its not working.
info : in old table i have multiple inserts in a same time.

Here is schema for my both table :

old stat ( that trigger not working on it)

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[stats](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
      [Code] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Stat] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  =    ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON, FILLFACTOR = 80) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
```

and new test stat ( that trigger works on it) :

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Teststats](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
      [Code] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Teststats] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  =    ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON, FILLFACTOR = 80) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
```

and here is my destination table on another db :

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[NewStat](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [StatID] [int] NULL,
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

The trigger works great on test table with same schema but in old stat table after creating trigger users cant insert in the old one anymore !

Comment: in your table `NewStat` is StatID only column ?

Comment: @Pranav , no there is id  column too , and its autoincreament

Comment: Might [`DISABLE TRIGGER`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189748.aspx) have been called against the old trigger? (Try an `ENABLE` and see if it changes)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever That was the case. Can u make this as an answer so that i can accept it please.

Answer (score -1):

You have your wrong insert statement So it doesn't execute trigger.
The correct one is as follows.

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[Vtriggers] ON [dbo].[stats]
FOR INSERT
AS
INSERT  INTO [NewDB].dbo.NewStat
        ( StatID )
VALUES  ( ID )
```

Comment: it gives the error on ID "Invalid column name 'ID'."
the statement above works on new table with same schema.

Answer (score -1):

Try This :-

```
create TRIGGER [dbo].[Vtriggers] ON [dbo].[stats]
FOR INSERT
AS
INSERT INTO [NewDB].dbo.NewStat (StatID) values(SELECT max(ID)
FROM inserted)
```

Comment: i have done this and still no insert in both table , but the command itself "INSERT INTO [NewDB].dbo.NewStat (StatID) values(SELECT max(ID) from [db].[dbo].[stats])"
works perfectly

Comment: It means Inserted table has no row... Do one thing .. Drop all the triggers from `stats` table ..then create new trigger and then try..

Comment: have done that , im always remove the last one creating another trigger. something else , the inserted table have a lots of row in it , i should mention the statment works with max keywords too , but none of them works inside trigger.

Comment: You've taken a trigger that *should* work for multi-row inserts and replaced it with one that is *broken* for multi-row inserts.